# What experimental bounds do we have on big $G$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, measurements, physical-constants, metrology

I know that there has been a large amount of controversy surrounding the exact value of the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) $G$, but I know that there is not a substantial difference in the measured value. So I was wondering what experimental bounds we have on it so far?

Comment: we don't have even good experimental bounds on torsion

Comment: What is torsion? In gravitational theory.

Answer (score 2):

This page shows the range of some measurements from 1982 to 2014. Basically, it looks like arguments could be made for any value between -460 to +250 parts per million below or above the commonly accepted value of 6.67408 x 10^-11 m^3 kg^-1 s^-2.

http://iupap.org/working-groups/wg13-newtonian-constant-of-gravitation/

Answer (score 1):

According to NIST[constants](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/index.html), as of 2017, 
$$G =  6.674 08(31) \times 10^{-11} \space {\rm m}^3 {\rm kg}^{-1} {\rm s}^{-2}    $$
which means the range is 6.67377 to 6.67439

It's not the easiest measurement to make, large forces from electrical, magnetic, and other sources have to be considered.

Comment: Isn't the number in brackets the standard deviation in the results? That is, G could conceivably be > 6.67439, but the probability of that is < 32%.

Comment: @Allure That's possible, but it could also be a hard limit based on systematics (nonrandom variables).   I tracked a paper that gives experimental results, Phys Rev Lett 23(10), from 1969, but I only have the reference, haven't visited the library.

Comment: @allure that's not the meaning of a confidence interval. In 68% of the hypothetical repeat experiments, an interval produced in that manner would include the true $G$, were the model true